# Global differential forms on Fano varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth rationally connected variety (say in characteristic zero).  Then it is straightforward to prove that $H^0(X,(\Omega_X^1)^{\otimes m}) = 0$ for all $m > 0$ since there is a very free rational curve $f: \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow X$ for which $f^* T_X$ is ample (see for example *Rational Curves on Algebraic Varieties* by J. Kollár, chapter IV).  In fact, the vanishing of these cohomology groups conjecturally characterizes rationally connected varieties.

However, this doesn't seem to immediately rule out the existence of a nonzero global $m$-form for some $m > 1$, since $\Omega^m_X$ is a quotient of $(\Omega_X^1)^{\otimes m}$.

> **Question.** Are there any rationally connected (or even Fano) varieties with nonzero global differential $m$-forms?

For $X$ smooth Fano of dimension $n$, we would necessarily have $1 < m < n$.

Comment: In characteristic $0$, $\Omega_X^m$ is a summand of $(\Omega^1_X)^{\otimes m}$, not just a quotient, so the vanishing argument goes through.

Comment: Thanks Will!  I forgot about that fact.

Answer (score 5):

For Fano manifolds in characteristic $0$, we can also use the following argument.

By Dolbeault theorem and Hodge symmetry we get, for any compact Kähler manifold $X$ and for any $m>0$, the isomorphism $$H^0(X, \, \Omega^m_X)\simeq H^m(X, \, \mathcal{O}_X) =H^m(X, \, K_X \otimes K_X^{-1}).$$ If $X$ is Fano then $K_X^{-1}$ is ample and so the last group is zero by Kodaira vanishing theorem.

Comment: A variant of this argument also shows that $H^2(X,T_X)$ vanishes, so that deformations of complex Fano manifolds are unobstructed.  In positive characteristic, we have neither of these.